# Kubectl commands showing "Unable to connect to the server: EOF" Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kops

I have created K8s cluster on my AWS account. But the `kubectl` commands don't work. I'm getting the following error:

`kubectl get nodes
Unable to connect to the server: EOF`

Please note that the "get pods,get svc and ns" are also showing the above error.

`kops version
Version 1.9.2 (git-cb54c6a52)`


`kubectl version
v1.9.4`

```
kubectl cluster-info

Kubernetes master is running at https://api-testkops-k8s-loca-uaofd1-10542275541138.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com

To further debug and diagnose cluster problems, use 'kubectl cluster-info dump'.
Unable to connect to the server: EOF
```

How can I resolve the issue? Please help.

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: @Steven Lung    Does the from where you are trying to execute kubectl commands have network connectivity to AWS ? Could you chk security groups of the load balancers or system that you are trying to connect ?